# How to disable date of a specific day of week in igx-date-picker in angular 10?

Tags: angular

I want to disable the date for every day in the week except a certain day(let's say Saturday). Currently, I can disable all the weekdays using **disabledDates** accessor of igxdatepickercomponent but it is still not disabling Sunday.

So is there any other method or workaround to disable all except a single day of the week?

Comment: Hi. Can you provide a Stackblitz ?

Comment: I think you need to create your own method return an array of dates corresponding to every sundays and add the array to `disabledDates` this way `{type: DateRangeType.Specific, dateRange: yourArrayOfSundays}`.

Comment: I can use this workaround but I do not want to make an array of Sundays. I mean there are like infinite sundays